# How to prevent Windows 10 Touch Keyboard from highlighting selected Keys

Tags: keyboard, on-screen-keyboard, touch-keyboard

We are having an issue with windows 10 touch keyboard not recognizing our password boxes in our front end, and highlighting keystrokes while entering passwords. I would like to solve one of two issues.

1. What needs to be changed on our password box for the keyboard to recognize what it is.
2. How to disable Windows Touch Keyboard key highlighting altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this is a Windows 10 feature. There is a button that shows up on the keyboard (shown in fig.1) only while selecting a password field. This button toggles key highlighting while entering passwords only.

[Fig.1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/88QB5.png)